# Python slowly scrapes websites

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've implemented news website scraper that scrapes by using Selenium web driver to access dynamic web pages and BeautifulSoup to retrieve the content. While parsing websites, I'm also writing scraped data to MongoDB storage and downloading pictures. I want to implement full news search by given category or by text, that appears in the news content. What can be the suggestions in terms of parallelization/adding async code to speed up the performance?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from mongo_setup import Database
import gridfs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
import time
import logging
import re
import pymongo


PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DRIVER_BIN = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "bin/chromedriver")


class Scraper:

    tsn_resource = 'https://tsn.ua/'
    ukrnet_resource = 'https://www.ukr.net/'

    db_name = 'scraper_db'
    category_coll = 'categories'
    articles_coll = 'articles'


    def __init__(self, limit=10):
        self.limit = limit  # max number of articles per category
        self.db = Database(self.db_name).connect_db()
        self.category_coll = self.init_collection(self.category_coll)
        self.articles_coll = self.init_collection(self.articles_coll)
        self.logger = self.init_logger()
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = DRIVER_BIN)
        self.image_storage = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "image_storage/")


    def init_logger(self):
        '''
        Initialize log file.
        '''
        logger = logging.getLogger('scraper_app')
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        # create a file handler
        handler = logging.FileHandler('scraper_logfile.log')
        handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        # create a logging format
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        # add the handlers to the logger
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        return logger


    def init_collection(self, name):
        if name in self.db.collection_names():
            self.db[name].drop()
        return self.db[name]


    def insert_one_to_collection(self, data, collection):
        try:
            collection.insert_one(data)
        except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
            pass

    def insert_many_to_collection(self, data, collection):
        try:
            collection.insert_many(data)
        except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
            pass


    def download_image(self, image_url):
        '''
        download images from news articles
        to local storage
        '''
        if not image_url.startswith(("data:image", "javascript")):
            local_filename = image_url.split('/')[-1].split("?")[0]

            r = requests.get(image_url, stream=True, verify=False)
            with open(self.image_storage + local_filename, 'wb') as f:
                for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                    f.write(chunk)


    def upload_image_to_mongo(self, image_url):
        response = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
        fs = gridfs.GridFS(self.db)
        img = response.raw.read()
        fs.put(img, filename=local_filename)


    def get_page_content(self, url):
        try:
            self.driver.get(url)
        except WebDriverException:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = DRIVER_BIN)
        page = self.driver.page_source
        return page


    def parse_page_content(self, url, parser_lib):
        page_obj = self.get_page_content(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_obj, parser_lib)
        return soup


    def tsn_categories(self):
        categories = self.gather_categories(self.tsn_resource, 'ul.c-app-nav-more-list li a')
        return categories

    def ukrnet_categories(self):
        categories = self.gather_categories(self.ukrnet_resource, 'h2.feed__section--title a')
        return categories


    def gather_categories(self, url, selector):
        categories = []
        soup = self.parse_page_content(url, "html.parser")
        all_categories = soup.select(selector)

        for item in all_categories:
            category = {}
            link = str(item.attrs.get('href'))
            if link.startswith('javascript'):
                continue
            if not link.startswith('https:'):
                link = 'https:' + link
            category['link'] = link
            category['name'] = item.get_text().strip()
            categories.append(category)

        self.insert_many_to_collection(categories, self.category_coll)
        return categories


    def search_by_category(self, category_name):
        category_name = category_name.decode('utf-8')
        category_list = []
        category_list += self.tsn_categories()
        category_list += self.ukrnet_categories()
        category_obj = next(item for item in category_list if item['name'] == category_name)
        link = category_obj['link']
        if 'ukr.net' in link:
            articles = self.get_ukrnet_articles(category_name, link)
        else:
            articles = self.get_tsn_articles(category_name, link)
        return articles


    def get_ukrnet_articles(self, category_name, url):
        '''
        retrieve all articles from ukr.net by given category link
        '''
        count = 0
        result = []
        soup = self.parse_page_content(url, "html.parser")
        all_articles = soup.select('div.im-tl a')
        for item in all_articles:
            if count <= self.limit:
                article = {}
                link = item.attrs.get('href')
                article['link'] = link
                article['category'] = category_name
                article['content'] = item.contents[0].encode('utf-8')
                result.append(article)
                self.insert_one_to_collection(article, self.articles_coll)
            else:
                break
            count += 1

        return result


    def get_tsn_articles(self, category_name, url):
        '''
        retrieve all articles from tsn.ua by given category link
        '''
        count = 0
        result = []

        data = []  # temporary storage

        # first parse through the list of articles
        soup = self.parse_page_content(url, "html.parser")
        all_articles = soup.select('div.c-entry-embed a.c-post-img-wrap')
        for item in all_articles:

            # iterate limit amount of articles
            if count <= self.limit:
                article = {}
                link = item.attrs.get('href')
                img_src = item.find('img').get('src')
                if link.endswith(".html"):
                    article['link'] = link
                    if img_src is not None:
                        article['img_src'] = img_src
                        self.download_image(img_src)

                    article['category'] = category_name
                    data.append(article)
                count += 1
            else:
                break

        # then iterate over each article
        for article in data:
            new_soup = self.parse_page_content(article['link'], "html5lib")
            news_content = new_soup.select('div.e-content p')

            text_content = [] # article content
            for chunk in news_content:
                text_content.append(chunk.get_text().strip(''))
            article_text = ' '.join(text_content)

            news_header = new_soup.select('div.c-post-meta h1') # article title
            if news_header:
                header_text = "".join(news_header[0].contents)

            article_image = new_soup.find('figure', class_='js-lightgallery')
            if article_image:
                img_src = article_image.find('img').get('src') # articles image
                self.download_image(img_src)

            news_chunk = {}
            news_chunk['category'] = article['category']
            news_chunk['link'] = article['link']
            news_chunk['title'] = header_text
            # news_chunk['title'] = ''
            news_chunk['content'] = article_text
            news_chunk['images'] = []
            if 'img_src' in article:
                news_chunk['images'].append(article['img_src']) # caption image
            if article_image:
                news_chunk['images'].append(img_src) # article image

            result.append(news_chunk)
            self.insert_one_to_collection(news_chunk, self.articles_coll)

        return result

    def search_by_text(self, text):
        category_links = []
        category_links += self.ukrnet_categories()
        category_links += self.tsn_categories()
        result = self.website_search_by_text(text, category_links)
        return result


    def website_search_by_text(self, text_searched, category_links):
        result = []

        text_searched = text_searched.decode('utf-8')
        for link in category_links:
            article = {}
            soup = self.parse_page_content(link['link'], "html.parser")
            all_articles = soup.find_all('a', text=re.compile(text_searched))
            for item in all_articles:
                article['link'] = item.attrs.get('href')
                article['category'] = link['name']
                article['content'] = (item.contents[0].strip()).encode('utf-8')
                self.insert_one_to_collection(article, self.articles_coll)
                result.append(article)
        return result


    def collect_ukrnet_articles(self):
        '''
        outdated
        '''
        categories = self.ukrnet_categories()

        for category in categories:
            count = 0
            soup = self.parse_page_content(category['link'], "html.parser")

            all_articles = soup.select('div.im-tl a')
            for item in all_articles:
                # only 10 first articles
                if count < self.limit:
                    article = {}
                    link = item.attrs.get('href')
                    article['link'] = link
                    article['category'] = category['name']
                    article['content'] = item.contents[0].encode('utf-8')
                    self.insert_one_to_collection(article, self.articles_coll)
                else:
                    break
                count += 1


    def run(self):
        self.search_by_category('Economics', self.tsn_categories())
        self.search_by_text('Economics')
        self.driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = Scraper()
    scraper.run()
```

Comment: Will be scrape from 1 website or from multiple websites?

Comment: There are some asynchronous options for python, but at that point you're going out of your way to avoid learning javascript. Also lxml will perform better than beautiful soup.

Comment: @Andreas scraping is done from 2 websites (they are defined as tsn_resource and ukrnet_resource)

Comment: Have you profiled it?

Answer (score 1):

[scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) is a solid python framework that automatically does things async/parallel.

There's also [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) that's been conveniently put into one package.

And then there's [multithreading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), also conveniently put into one package.

With the multithreading library there's a way to call the function you're trying to thread with `map()` and then pass the lists/variables you're trying to use with it. `map(your_func, your_list)`
I don't remember the exact link, or structure for it, but it's a quick google search away. Really makes it easier.